# MySQL root password reset -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: mysql, bash, reset

I am just starting to learn MySQL, im running 5.7.20 on Mac os 10.12 when i tried to use the following command in Terminal to reset password

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('password')
```

i am keep getting

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Can anyone assist me with that error message? i have tried many different website no one seems to have an answer to that.

```
Last login: Tue May 28 02:07:04 on ttys001
192-168-1-5:~ Betty$ mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('password')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see `mysql> something`, it doesn't mean to type `mysql> something` at the Bash prompt. It means to type `something` at the MySQL prompt. Run the command properly from inside MySQL and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run mysql command from within bash you may want to use `-e` option as in:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword -e "UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('password')"
```